# Titan - Schema Agreement In Cassandra Cluster

Tags: scala, cassandra, titan

I'm blocked by a problem I'm having with my brand new Cassandra cluster that I use with Titan. The cluster has 3 nodes and the problem comes when I try to open the graph for the first time with *TitanFactory.open()*. This is the exception:

> WARN  09:13:44 UnknownColumnFamilyException reading from socket;
>   closing org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't
>   find table for cfId 9ca7a420-b843-11e5-8108-d94de8194139. If a table
>   was just created, this is likely due to the schema not being fully
>   propagated.  Please wait for schema agreement on table creation.
>           at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData$Serializer.deserialize(CFMetaData.java:1319)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand$Serializer.deserialize(ReadCommand.java:586)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand$Serializer.deserialize(ReadCommand.java:523)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageIn.read(MessageIn.java:98) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessage(IncomingTcpConnection.java:199)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessages(IncomingTcpConnection.java:176)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:92)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]

This is my Configuration:

```
def open(keyspace: String = "titan"): BaseConfiguration = {

    var conf = new BaseConfiguration()
    conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandrathrift")
    conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX")
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.keyspace", keyspace)
    conf.setProperty("storage.batch-loading", true)
    conf.setProperty("storage.buffer-size", 4096)
    conf.setProperty("storage.read-attempts", 300)
    conf.setProperty("storage.write-attempts", 300)
    conf.setProperty("storage.attempt-wait", 200000000)
    conf.setProperty("storage.read-time", 200000000)
    conf.setProperty("storage.lock-wait-time", 200000000)
    conf.setProperty("storage.connection-timeout", 200000000)
    conf.setProperty("storage.read-time", 200000000)
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.replication-factor", 3)
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.frame-size-mb", 1024)
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.thrift.cpool.when-exhausted", "GROW")
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.thrift.cpool.max-active", -1)
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.thrift.cpool.evictor-period", -1)
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.thrift.cpool.min-evictable-idle-time", -1)

    conf.setProperty("ids.block-size", 20000000)

    conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache", true)
    conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-clean-wait", 20)
    conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-time", 1800000)
    conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-size", 0.25)

    conf
}
```

The problem seems to be the schema agreement when Cassandra create the table. There is a way for waiting the schema agreement between all nodes? Actually I'm using Cassandra 3.0.2 with Titan 1.0.0.

Comment: Note that Titan 1.0 is listed as compatible with Cassandra 2.1.x http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html

Comment: I changed the version of Cassandra (2.1.12) but the result is the same

Comment: NTP setup? Is there any time drift between nodes?

Comment: The clocks of the nodes are synchronized with NTP. How can I check if there is a time drift?

Comment: Shot in the dark: but are all the C* nodes actually healthy? There are also several of your configuration factors which look suspiciously large: `ids.block-size` and `storage.cassandra.frame-size-mb` and most of the timeouts. I don't know why these would cause the problem you're seeing, but you might consider reverting to the defaults and see if that helps anything.

Comment: I tried to change the configuration but nothing changed

Comment: Where can I find an example of Titan that use a Cassandra Cluster?

Comment: Assuming your Cassandra cluster is configured correctly, all you need to connect Titan to a Cassandra cluster is to set `storage.backend` to cassandra or cassandrathrift, and then `storage.hostname` to a comma-separated list of Cassandra nodes IPs. None of the other properties you listed are required to test this out.

Comment: The configs of my Cassandra Cluster (two nodes with ip1 for the seed)  are:
`auto_bootstrap: false,
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "ip1",
concurrent_counter_writes: 128,
listen_address: ip1 (ip2),
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0,
broadcast_rpc_address: ip1 (ip2),
cross_node_timeout: true,
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`. There is something wrong?

Comment: I've tried only with `storage.backend` (cassandrathrift) and `storage.hostname` (ip1, ip2) but the problem does not go away.

Comment: Could be the problem the frequent change of keyspace?